# Filter Search Results using Attribute and Category

Tags: product-attribute, catalogsearch

I have a custom requirement where I need to change the catalog search results.

What I need to do is to show the products based on attribute as well as category

For example if you search attribute `pink`, it will list down all the products on search page having the attribute `pink` assigned to them

Similarly, if a product is only assigned to category `X` and when you search `X`, it will list down all the products with category `X` assigned.

Do I need to change the Catalogsearch Model ?

How can I achieve this ?

Please Help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want an attribute to be searchable then you can set the flag `is_searchable` on this attribute, either via the admin section or via a set-up script.

As for the categories as far as I am aware Magento will not do this by default, so you will need to create a module for this.

Comment: You could use anchored categories everywhere, then they are searchable.